# How to set a text of label in javascript by using the text of dynamically generated label's?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
{
SqlDataReader reader = cmdAuthors.ExecuteReader();
           RadioButton rb;
           Label lb;
           while(reader.Read()){
             rb=new RadioButton();
             lb=new Label();
             lb.Text=reader[0].ToString();
           rb.Attributes.Add("OnClick","getSelectedAuthor('"+lb.Text.ToString()+"')");
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(rb);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

            }
}
```

// I dont know what to write in this function  in order to Label2.text=Text;
    // document.getElementById("Label2").value=text does not work

function getSelectedAuthor(text) {

}

```
 <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2"  runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's Label2's ClientID, also check innerHTML/innerText, not value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the value using innerHTML rather than value, e.g.

```
document.getElementById("Label2").innerHTML = 'text';
```